# Calling backend docker container from frontend + client side vs server side rendering

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, svelte, server-side-rendering

I'm currently working on a full stack application using Spring-boot (Kotlin), SvelteKit (run with Vite), and MongoDB, each with their own Docker container. My backend service is being forwarded to port 6868 on my localhost, and when I run my frontend service with "npm run dev" locally (which triggers this script): `vite dev --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080` and remove the service from my docker-compose.yml (see frontend-svelte service in docker-compose below), I am able to call my backend at localhost:6868 (see +page.js below). However, when I run my frontend inside of a docker container, the request to localhost:6868 fails. This sort of makes sense to me since localhost:6868 would refer to the inside of the docker container if the code was being sent from the server (docker container) as opposed to the browser. When I change localhost:6868 to spring-boot:8080 (the docker container) the initial request sent Server side does succeed (i.e. the console log below in /frontend-svelte/routes/+page.js does print out) however, there is still an error in the browser for the subsequent requests being sent from the client side. It seems to me that the issue is the discrepancy caused by requests sent from client-side vs server-side, so how can I resolve this issue? Thanks everyone for your help!

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db

  spring-boot:
    image: bracket_backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dev.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 6868:8080
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes: 
      - ./backend/src:/app/src
    env_file:
      - ./.env
      
  frontend-svelte:
    image: bracket_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend-svelte
      dockerfile: Dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 1234:8080
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend-svelte/src:/app/src
    depends_on:
      - spring-boot


volumes:
  db:
```

/backend/Dev.Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./.mvn ./mvn
COPY ./mvnw ./
COPY ./pomDev.xml ./
# Note that src is mounted as a volume to allow code update w/o restarting container
ENTRYPOINT mvn spring-boot:run -f pomDev.xml
```

/frontend-svelte/Dev.Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY svelte.config.js .
COPY vite.config.js .
COPY jsconfig.json .
COPY playwright.config.js .
# Note that src is mounted so changes will occur.
ENTRYPOINT npm run dev
```

/frontend-svelte/routes/+page.js (this is where the request to the backend is made. This succeeds if not run from docker container)

```
import { getBaseUrl } from '$lib/utils.js';
 
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ params }) {
    console.log("test")
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:6868/api/groups`); // THIS LINE MAKES THE REQUEST TO THE BACKEND



    console.log("respoonse is: ");
    console.log(response);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    return response.json()
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: @dududornelees sorry for the late response! Yeah, the issue is that load functions in +page.js run on both the server (the first time) and the browser (subsequently) (unless const ssr = false) is specified. So since the first request is being sent from the server instead of the browser, localhost:6868 refers to the inside of the docker container instead of the local port which the container is bound to. If you want to send a request to localhost instead of the docker container, you would need to specify const ssr=false so that page.js only sends a request client side and not from the server

Comment: source: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load# this page explains it too